# What exactly is a 電気風呂 (denki furo)?

Tags: japan, hot-springs

I’ve been to a number of sentou (public bath) and onsen (hot spring bath) all over Japan by now. In some of these (both sentou and onsen), I saw bathtubs labelled 電気風呂. I know enough Japanese kanji to read this as *denki furo* or *electric bath* but I do not know enough Japanese to understand what this is about (and arguably I might be reading it wrong and thus attempting to understand it wrong).

All the sources I could find by Googling are in Japanese and thus way above my level.

Surely a 電気風呂 isn’t a bath with an electric current going through it, but then what in the world is it?

Note: I have not been brave enough to just go inside and try it out.

Comment: I see that Wiktionary has an entry here: [電気風呂](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%9B%BB%E6%B0%97%E9%A2%A8%E5%91%82), looks like your reading is correct.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. The one I went to had different strengths of electricity, and also the strength depended on your distance from the electrodes at the back. If you do try it, I recommend starting further out and wait for a while, see how it feels, and gradually work your way inwards as a pace you're happy with.

Comment: "Surely a 電気風呂 isn’t a bath with an electric current going through it" Oh, but that's *exactly* what it is

Comment: Only in Japan ;-)

Answer (score 13):

The 電気風呂 passes a mild electric current so when you sit between the electrodes, you feel a slight tingly feeling. It’s usually one of the many different types of individual bath options (including jet baths) that a super bathhouse (スーパー銭湯) might have.

They warn people with weak hearts or pacemakers shouldn’t use the devices and I have to heartily (pun intended) agree.

Comment: And when getting zapped with electricity seems too tame, you can glow with good health after a radioactive bath! https://forum.gaijinpot.com/forum/living-in-japan/health-fitness/81931-what-s-the-deal-with-radium-radon-baths-healthy-or-carcinogenic

Comment: Radon hot springs/baths are actually quite common throughout the world! But another interesting type of onsen is those with little fish which are supposed to eat the dead skin on your body

Comment: @xuq01 unrelated to the question: Copenhagen's aquarium has a small tank where you can put your arms up to the elbows in order to be devoured by those fishes. It feels quite good.